# Repeatedly calling python from Java in the most efficient way

Tags: java, python, jython

I have several python scripts (eg `a.py`,`b.py`) that share the same overhead at the top, eg:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
#and some Oracle database connection and reading.
```

Then I have a java script that users Runtime to calls these several python scripts separately:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python a.py");
p.waitFor();
...
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python b.py");
p.waitFor();
```

I suffer from the repeated overhead due to the java Runtime and python import overhead during each python call. I am wondering whether there is a way that involves only one time overhead during the first python call (by passing around some python handler/state maybe?) I am open to third party tools (eg Jython) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than launching each program separately and running to completion, create a "launcher" that reads from standard input, and interact with that launcher - this should be a program that won't exit until it's told to; its entire purpose is to launch other functions.

Then treat it as a resource and use it to call the individual functions and return results (rather than Java's `Process`).

The same strategy can be used for many different types of external programs that have shared dependencies - the launcher can load the common dependencies/ it's own runtime once, and more quickly call functions in those dependencies.

Comment: When you say "launcher", do you mean some logic model or some java tool/API (eg http://www.syncedit.com/software/javalauncher/)?

Comment: I'm just referring to a logical model, not a specific implementation. You could implement it with std-in, or reading from sockets/RPC, or whatever makes most sense based on the situation and tech you have.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will speed up your program, but one option would be to use Jython to start up a Python interpreter once, and then re-use it for multiple scripts. You just need to add a dependency on the Jython JAR (download it at http://www.jython.org/downloads.html or use Maven/Gradle/etc.)

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
public class JythonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PythonInterpreter pythonInterpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        pythonInterpreter.execfile("a.py");
        pythonInterpreter.execfile("b.py");
    }
}
```

Ref: http://tssblog.blogs.techtarget.com/2007/11/21/using-python-within-java/

Answer (score 1):

You could launch the Python script once and then communicate repeated tasks with it via some kinda of IPC (inter-process communication). Some ways that come to mind:

- Access via an HTTP API hosted by the Python process (Java process as the client)
- If using OS X/Linux use [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal)
- Something as simple as delivering instructions via a file - although you would probably need to implement file-locking (so the reader doesn't read an incomplete file if the writer hasn't finished)

However, implementing anyone of these does feels a bit like **premature-optimization**. Why not first implement the easiest way (as in your example), and profile your CPU usage. Chances are, your current approach won't make as much of a dent in your CPU usage as you might suspect.

Comment: I did CPU profiling, and the overhead was indeed there.